ROS2/Gazebo fuel.ignitionrobotics.org URL deprecated
I have installed ROS2 Humble + Gazebo Fortess on 22.04.1-Ubuntu.
I am following this documention https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Advanced/Simulators/Gazebo/Gazebo.html
When I run:
ign gazebo -v 4 -r visualize_lidar.sdf

I am getting this error:
libcurl: (60) SSL: certificate subject name '*' does not match target host name 'fuel.ignitionrobotics.org'
[Err] [FuelClient.cc:717] Failed to download model.
  Server: https://fuel.ignitionrobotics.org
  Route: openrobotics/models/playground/tip/playground.zip
  REST response code: 0
[Err] [Server.cc:139] Error Code 13: [/sdf/world[@name="visualize_lidar_world"]/include[0]/uri:/usr/share/ignition/ignition-gazebo6/worlds/visualize_lidar.sdf:L517]: Msg: Unable to find uri[https://fuel.ignitionrobotics.org/1.0/openrobotics/models/Playground]

And warning:
[Wrn] [FuelClient.cc:1978] The fuel.ignitionrobotics.org URL is deprecrated. Pleasse change https://fuel.ignitionrobotics.org to https://fuel.gazebosim.org

Also there is no $HOME/.ignition/fuel/config.yaml, and specifically no fuel folder.
But I do see /usr/share/ignition/ignition-gazebo6/ and /usr/share/ignition/gazebo6.yaml.
Any insights will be helpful. Not sure where  https://fuel.ignitionrobotics.org is being picked from, and how to change it.

I guess gazebo maintainers turned off the redirect from this domain. I get the same error on humble harmonic. You can download the models directly before you run the simulation. Simply use the new url:
ign fuel download -v4 --url "https://fuel.gazebosim.org/1.0/OpenRobotics/models/playground"

After you should be able to run it and a fuel folder should have been created. Also, make sure not to run a vpn, I had issues before.
